# Can I use a async function as a callback in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parallel-processing, lodash

Can I use an async function as a callback? Something like this:

```
await sequelize.transaction(async function (t1) {
    _.each(data,  async function (value)  {
        await DoWork(value);
    });
});
//Only after every "DoWork" is done?
doMoreWork();
```

As far as I understand there is no guarantee that the function invoking the callback will wait until the promise is solved before continuing. Right? The only way to be sure what will happen is to read the source code of the function the callback is passed to(e.g. source code of 'transaction')? Is there a good way to rewrite my sample to work properly no matter how the calling function is implemented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 2):

`async` function can be as a callback but only if returned value (a promise) is used in some way that helps to maintain correct control flow. An example is array `map` callback.

This is the same case as [this problem with `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop). The problem is that `transaction` uses a value from `async` callback (a promise) but a value from `each` callback is ignored.

The recipe for executing promises in series with `async` is `for..of` or other loop statement:

```
await sequelize.transaction(async function (t1) {
    for (const value of data)
        await DoWork(value);
});
```

The recipe for executing promises in parallel with `async` is `Promise.all` with `map`:

```
await sequelize.transaction(async function (t1) {
    await Promise.all(data.map(async (value) => {
        await DoWork(value);
    }));
});
```

`async` functions are left for reference only because the code doesn't benefit from them; these could be regular functions that return promises.